# pass variable to child in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass a variable in my parent window to an iframe html document (child).

Example: `var myValue = 10;`
want to pass `myValue` to a child element (hidden input)...

How would I do this?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  For example, are you doing this through a function in the parent window?  A function in the child window?  Are you creating and populating that iframe with JS, or does it exist somewhere already?

Comment: anyhow is easiest! I can create a function if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you:

http://cross-browser.com/talk/inter-frame_comm.html

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit skimpy on the details, but in principle you can find the IFRAME e.g. with document.getElementById() and then use contentDocument on it to get its document. Again with getElementById() you can then access the desired child element.

Obviously you'd have to give both element "id" attributes.

I think IE does not know contentDocument, so you might have to use contentWindow.document there.

Answer (score 1):

From the parent's context:
window.frames contains the frame you want. If the frame is in the same domain,
use getElementById/getElementsByName to locate your hidden input and assign it the value.

Answer (score 1):

Following on to Steffen's answer, I did something like this earlier today.

```
if(document.getElementById("foo").document) { // IE
    searchableContent = document.getElementById("foo").contentWindow.document;
}
if(document.getElementById("foo").contentDocument) { // Firefox, Chrome
    searchableContent = document.getElementById("foo").contentDocument;
}
```

[Object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) might be tangentially of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this should work. May need to be tweaked a bit.

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('iFrameId');

if ( myIframe.contentDocument ) { // DOM
    myIframe.contentDocument.getElementById('hiddenField').value = myValue;

} else if ( myIframe.contentWindow ) { // IE win
    myIframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = myValue;
}
```